# how to read parameters from console to method in groovy?

Tags: methods, groovy

I am new to groovy.I am reading values for 2 variables from console with  below lines of code.

```
System.in.withReader {   
  println "Version: "  
  version = it.readLine()  
  println "Doc Type:"  
  Doc=it.readLine()  
  call getBillID(version,Doc)
}
```

`getBillid` method is as below,

```
def getBillID(int version,int doc)
{  
  allNodes.BillID.each {
    theregularExpression=/\d+_\d+_\d+_\d_\d+_\d+_\d_${version}_${Doc}_\d+_\d+/
    if(it != "" && it =~ theregularExpression) {
      println "******" + it
    }
  }
}
```

now i want to use those variable values in my `getBILLID` method but i am getting error as

```
No signature of method: ReadXML.getBillID() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [9, ]
```

where i went wrong.can any one tell me plz..

Comment: And what type is allNodes?  It looks like the system is expecting to read from an XML file and the allNodes seems like it's XML oriented, which makes it hard to see how you're wanting to get values from the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Kalarani's answer, you could also do this:

```
System.in.withReader {
  print "Version: "
  int version = it.readLine() as int
  print "Doc Type: "
  int doc = it.readLine() as int
  getBillID( version, doc )
}
```

---

***As an aside;*** I would be careful with your capitalisation and variable names, ie: you have a variable called `Doc` with a capital letter.  This is not the standard naming scheme, and you are best using all lowercase for variable names.  You can see where it has got confused in the `getBillID` method.  The parameter is called `doc` (all lowercase), but in the regular expression you reference `${Doc}` (uppercase again).

This sort of thing is going to end up causing you a world of pain and bugs that might take you longer to find

Answer (score 0):

Where is the getBillId() method defined? and what is the signature of the method? It would help understanding your problem if you could post that.

Comment: That clearly explains the reason for the error. The method signature for getBillId() is expecting two integers, where you are invoking the method with two Strings. You can use version.toInteger() and Doc.toInteger() to convert the strings to integer and then pass it on to the method. This should fix the issue